# Upload files to database virus check

Tags: java, virus

As part of our requirements, we need to upload some files to database.  Is there any way we can do virus scan on those files before saving them to database.

Comment: You might want to add some more information.  Upload by what means, what environments are involved...  This is too vague to answer in its current form and will probably get closed if you don't add more useful information.

Comment: This is still in requirements process.  Did not come-up with plan yet.  We will use Java to retreive files from folder, scan them and load them to database.  Server will most likely be Windows( we are thinking of UNIX also).

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Free AVG](http://free.avg.com/) as my anti-virus program on my Windows machine. It comes with a command-line scanning utility which allows you to scan files manually. This could easily be executed from Java code.

I am sure some of the [other anti-virus applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_antivirus_software) also come with command-line versions of their scanners. Any of these would be easily executed from Java code.

If you are on a UNIX machine, you may want to question this requirement of virus scanning since UNIX viruses are very rare and the effective ones are not easily detectable by anti-virus software. The value of such a feature may be non-existent.

Comment: If your server is running on *nix but your uploaders and downloaders are commonly on Windows it's beneficial to scan for windows viruses even though they won't affect you.

Comment: @Stephen - Good point. It is true that if you are serving the files back out to users who are expecting your content to be safe, the server architecture does not matter; you need to scan the files regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Your *server* is probably not at risk from viruses; however, you probably want to check the files anyway - it is entirely possible for a Windows-using client to upload an infected file, and another Windows-using client to download it and infect themselves. By checking for malware at the server, you could stop it from spreading - so the net result is positive, even if the malware doesn't attack your server *directly*.

If your server runs something UN*X-ish (Linux, BSD, ...), you may want to look at [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/), and its Java bindings, [clamavj](http://code.google.com/p/clamavj/): these provide various scan capabilities (e.g. on-demand or automatic in a given location), even for different-platform malware (e.g. you can check for Windows viruses, even though your server runs Linux).

Comment: Can clamavj can be used in a Windows server? Or are there any better alternatives?

Comment: That would be better as a question,  not a comment. (I don't know, btw)